# Xamarin/monotouch get Facebook friends list

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I am trying to get friends list using xamarin/monotouch.

This is what i did:

```
if (FBSession.ActiveSession.IsOpen) {
            FBRequestConnection.StartWithGraphPath("me/friends?fields=id,name,picture,installed",(connection, result, error) => 
            {
                if (error == null) 
                {

                }
            });
        }
```

I am getting the result object and I can extract the data with:

```
result.ValueForKey (new NSString ("data"))
```

My question is how do I parse this data into user objects?
Usually I get Json response which I parse. What is the correct way to do this with the result object?

Thanks!

Comment: For an updated solution:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28564806/parse-facebook-friends-list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example that works for me:

```
var list = new List<FacebookFriend>();
var graphObject = result as FBGraphObject;

using (var array = (NSMutableArray)graphObject[new NSString("data")])
{
    for (uint i = 0; i < array.Count; i++)
    {
        using (var friend = new NSDictionary(array.ValueAt (i)))
        {
            friends.Add (new FacebookFriend
            {
                ID = friend.ObjectForKey (new NSString ("uid")).ToString (),
                Name = friend.ObjectForKey (new NSString ("name")).ToString (),
            });
        }
    }
}
```

This is inside the callback from the graph request.

`FacebookFriend` is just a simple class with the 2 properties I'm using.

Comment: Thanks. I don't understand why FB doesn't just return JSON.. I think this is a bug since on their docs for the SDK it lists JSON as the response.

Comment: This is actually FB's handy json parser, isn't it wonderful? It turns json into an NSMess.

Comment: @jonathanpeppers it stopped working in the unified api, do you know what's the updated code?

Comment: @UdiI I would post a new question with details on this, such as the error you're getting, etc. Link to the original question.

Comment: This is the new question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28564806/parse-facebook-friends-list