# Parse Facebook friends list

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin

Up until the unified api, I have used this code to parse Facebook's friends list:

```
var list = new List<FacebookFriend>();
var graphObject = result as FBGraphObject;

using (var array = (NSMutableArray)graphObject[new NSString("data")])
{
    for (uint i = 0; i < array.Count; i++)
    {
        using (var friend = new NSDictionary(array.ValueAt (i)))
        {
            friends.Add (new FacebookFriend
            {
                ID = friend.ObjectForKey (new NSString ("uid")).ToString (),
                Name = friend.ObjectForKey (new NSString ("name")).ToString (),
            });
        }
    }
}
```

FacebookFriends:

```
public class FacebookFriend
    {

        public string ID { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }

    }
```

array is as follows:

array {( { id = 100009010208340; name = "Patricia Amijajbjhcdj Wongsky"; }, { id = 100009036398265; name = "Patricia Amijcfcihbfe Vijayvergiyasen"; }, { id = 100009086915834; name = "Elizabeth Amijhfiaehcd Bharambesky"; } )}

But now the protection level of NSDictionary changed and this code breaks.
I've tried using some factory methods instead but with no success.

Does anyone know what should be used in this case instead of

```
new NSDictionary(array.ValueAt (i)))
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That should be like:

`Runtime.GetNSObject<NSDictionary> (array.ValueAt (i));`

Side note: creating the same `NSString` constants inside a loop is not efficient. You should do something like:

```
using (var uid = new NSString ("uid"))
using (var name = new NSString ("name")) {
    for (uint i = 0; i < array.Count; i++) {
       using (var friend = Runtime.GetNSObject<NSDictionary> (array.ValueAt (i))) {
        friends.Add (new FacebookFriend
        {
            ID = friend.ObjectForKey (uid).ToString (),
            Name = friend.ObjectForKey (name).ToString (),
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I´ve compiled the answer and added a get that might help someone, since it took me some days to figure out how to make this request work on the unified API and Facebook SDK V2.2 in Xamarin IOS.

```
List<string> mUserFriendsList = new List<string>();
    if(FBSession.ActiveSession.IsOpen)
                    {
                        var dic = new NSDictionary();
                        FBRequestConnection.StartWithGraphPath("me/friends?fields=id",dic,"GET",(connection,result,error) =>
                        {
                            if(error != null){
                                Console.WriteLine(error.Description);
                                InvokeOnMainThread (() => new UIAlertView ("Error!", "An error has occured while trying to connect to facebook. Please try again later.", null, "Ok", null).Show ());
                            }else{
                                var graphObject = result as FBGraphObject;
                                using (var array = (NSMutableArray)graphObject[new NSString("data")])
                                {
                                     using(var id = new NSString("id"));
                                     for (uint i = 0; i < array.Count; i++) 
                                     {
                                        using (var friend = Runtime.GetNSObject<NSDictionary> (array.ValueAt (i))) 
                                        {
                                            mUserFriend = friend["id"].ToString ();
                                            mUserFriendsList.Add (mUserFriend);
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    }
```